# Changing the position of a dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the position and style of a dynamically added element, but my changes are not taking affect. Any ideas why?

I appreciate your assistance.

```
function addButtons()
{
  var button1 = document.createElement('button');

  button1.innerHTML = 'Relevant';

  button1.onclick = function()
  {
    alert('test');
    return false;
  };


  document.getElementsByClassName('subject')[0].appendChild(button1).style.left="6000px";


};
```

Comment: If the element doesn't have `position: absolute`,  `position: fixed` or  `position: relative`, `left` does not have any effect.

Comment: @FelixKling you are correct. Works like a charm now. Feel free to to add this comment as an answer, and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If the element doesn't have `position: absolute`,  `position: fixed` or  `position: relative`,  either as inline style or inherited from stylesheets, `left` does not have any effect